# How do I embed a JPG thumbnail to a ogg/opus audio file with a script?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, youtube-dl, ogg

I am using youtube-dl to download ogg audio files with their respective thumbnail, but I am not sure how to embed the thumbnail into the audio file.

Comment: You have already 4 reopen votes (5 are needed), a reopen is likely. Good luck on the site!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ogg format do not support explicitly embedding images. What you can do is to convert the image to base64 and add it under custom tag/comment.

You can check [this Q/A](https://superuser.com/q/169151/409497) for more details

Answer (score 2):

This problem has been addressed and solved in [this](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/22338) issue. However, it has not yet been merged, so it is not yet available via the official release. Also, you may have already downloaded the opus files and thumbnails.

I use this script, which goes through all files ending with `opus` in a folder and adds the corresponding file ending with `jpg` as thumbnail. You need to make sure that both files are present and have the same name, there are no safety checks implemented.

I just copy-pasted the part of the code which [tripulse](https://github.com/tripulse) implemented in the issue mentioned above. All credit goes to tripulse. It requires the `mutagen` python package, that can be easily installed via `pip`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from glob import glob
from mutagen.oggopus import OggOpus
from mutagen.flac import Picture
from base64 import b64encode

ext_audio = 'opus'
ext_thumb = 'jpg'


for f in glob('*.{}'.format(ext_audio)):
    thumb = f.rstrip(ext_audio) + ext_thumb

    covart = Picture()
    covart.data = open(thumb, 'rb').read()
    covart.type = 3  # Cover (front)

    audio = OggOpus(f)
    audio['metadata_block_picture'] = b64encode(covart.write()).decode('ascii')

    audio.save()
```